# How can I configure default VS Code namespaces for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, namespaces

How can I configure default VS Code namespaces for C#?

E.g. I have the following folders structure:

```
gameplay/input/controllers/foo.cs
```

I created the `foo.cs` by right clicking the `controllers` folder and selecting `New C# Class`. And here is how the class looks by default without any changes from my side:

```
namespace play.input.controllers
{
    public class foo
    {
        
    }
}
```

While I would expect the namespace in this case to be `gameplay.input.controllers`.
I am confused why would VS Code change the `gameplay` to `play`? How could I fix it?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

I can not find the `RootNamespace` in my project:

[image]

So, the provided answer has no value for me.

Comment: The default namespace is the project name.  When you create a new project VS defaults to the user document folder (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 20XX\Projects or last folder used for creating a project) and increments the type of project by one like WindowsApplication1 to WindowsApplication2.  If you change the name of the project in the GUI the namespace will change.

Comment: In Unity my project is called `pla`. How can I find out and change my project name in VS Code?

Comment: To change project name you can use Solution Explorer and right click the items in the explorer to rename an object.  Namespaces can simply be edited in VS but in some cases you may need to change references in other places in the code.  If you get a compiler error simply click on the error and then change the name where the error occurs.

Comment: What items should I click in solution explorer?

Comment: The first row is the project name and the second row is the root namespace.  Changing the names will make multiple changes to the project name (the csproj file) and the namespace.  I would do a clean build after changing to make sure everything still compiles.  There are properties like the starting namespace that sometimes doesn't get changed.  You can click on the error in the error list to find where the error is occurring.  Some changes you have to search the project properties to find the error.  Errors I can't find I close the project and open the csproj file in notepad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In **Visual Studio**, you can set the default namespace of a project in Project Preferences->Application under "Default Namespace".

In **VS Code** or manually, you can edit the project file to include the `RootNamespace` tag, as follows:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
....
    <RootNamespace>MyRootNamespace</RootNamespace>
....
    
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The string that is specified as the Root Namespace is used for new files in the root directory of the project. If you create items in subfolders, the subfolder names will be included in the namespace by default.

If you want to remove the application name from the namespace (`play` in your case), you can define the default namespace as empty.

Comment: Where can I find the `Project Preferences`?

Comment: @some1here: Right-Click on a project in the solution explorer and select "Properties". It's the last entry in the context menu. (Sorry for being inexact, my VS version is localized)

Comment: Are you talking about VS? My question was about VS Code.

Comment: @some1here: OK, I don't use the later, but I suppose it must be very similar.

Comment: No, it is not the same.

Comment: Yeah the question was about VS Code, it's directly mentioned in the question.  Not sure why this is the accepted answer.

Comment: @RyanMann The second solution using the `RootNamespace` tag is correct. It worked for me in vscode with `C# Extensions`. That's why the OP marked it as accepted.